# How to install small PHP scripts for tools into pages of an existing website?

Tags: php, wordpress

First of all, I'm a physician and not a technical expert whatsoever like you, so please bear with me :D

I want to build a website that offers online tools like "email extracting", "image resizing", etc, and I was wondering how to install tools with small PHP scripts like 1-2 .php files, and have them on different pages in the existing website "[internettoolkits.com](https://internettoolkits.com/)"?

Other tools I found, have more folders and files and most videos talk about databases and playing with file managers, and for those, I decided to create a subdomain for each, following the advises of creating new database and updating the file manager since they have an admin and user areas. (according to my understanding)

But for the small ones that don't require admin and user areas, like email extracting tool, can I have the php scripts added to a page/post in wordpress like with using HTML scripts? I tried the HTML scripts and they work fine (you can see examples on that website)

- Do I insert them in specific files in the file manager and how to do it to make it appear in a designated page called "Thumbnail Generator Tool" for example?
- Do I need to create a specific database for each of those small tools or not?

I tried using plugins (code snippet) and (insert PHP code snippet) and both didn't work

Example of tool to have: Thumbnail generator tool that have 2 files below:
first file (image.class.php)

```js
<?php

###############################################################
# Thumbnail Image Class for Thumbnail Generator
###############################################################
# For updates visit http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/
############################################################### 

class Zubrag_image {

  var $save_to_file = true;
  var $image_type = -1;
  var $quality = 100;
  var $max_x = 100;
  var $max_y = 100;
  var $cut_x = 0;
  var $cut_y = 0;
 
  function SaveImage($im, $filename) {
 
    $res = null;
 
    // ImageGIF is not included into some GD2 releases, so it might not work
    // output png if gifs are not supported
    if(($this->image_type == 1)  && !function_exists('imagegif')) $this->image_type = 3;

    switch ($this->image_type) {
      case 1:
        if ($this->save_to_file) {
          $res = ImageGIF($im,$filename);
        }
        else {
          header("Content-type: image/gif");
          $res = ImageGIF($im);
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        if ($this->save_to_file) {
          $res = ImageJPEG($im,$filename,$this->quality);
        }
        else {
          header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
          $res = ImageJPEG($im, NULL, $this->quality);
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        if (PHP_VERSION >= '5.1.2') {
          // Convert to PNG quality.
          // PNG quality: 0 (best quality, bigger file) to 9 (worst quality, smaller file)
          $quality = 9 - min( round($this->quality / 10), 9 );
          if ($this->save_to_file) {
            $res = ImagePNG($im, $filename, $quality);
          }
          else {
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            $res = ImagePNG($im, NULL, $quality);
          }
        }
        else {
          if ($this->save_to_file) {
            $res = ImagePNG($im, $filename);
          }
          else {
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            $res = ImagePNG($im);
          }
        }
        break;
    }
 
    return $res;
 
  }
 
  function ImageCreateFromType($type,$filename) {
   $im = null;
   switch ($type) {
     case 1:
       $im = ImageCreateFromGif($filename);
       break;
     case 2:
       $im = ImageCreateFromJpeg($filename);
       break;
     case 3:
       $im = ImageCreateFromPNG($filename);
       break;
    }
    return $im;
  }
 
  // generate thumb from image and save it
  function GenerateThumbFile($from_name, $to_name) {
 
    // if src is URL then download file first
    $temp = false;
    if (substr($from_name,0,7) == 'http://') {
      $tmpfname = tempnam("tmp/", "TmP-");
      $temp = @fopen($tmpfname, "w");
      if ($temp) {
        @fwrite($temp, @file_get_contents($from_name)) or die("Cannot download image");
        @fclose($temp);
        $from_name = $tmpfname;
      }
      else {
        die("Cannot create temp file");
      }
    }

    // check if file exists
    if (!file_exists($from_name)) die("Source image does not exist!");
    
    // get source image size (width/height/type)
    // orig_img_type 1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG
    list($orig_x, $orig_y, $orig_img_type, $img_sizes) = @GetImageSize($from_name);

    // cut image if specified by user
    if ($this->cut_x > 0) $orig_x = min($this->cut_x, $orig_x);
    if ($this->cut_y > 0) $orig_y = min($this->cut_y, $orig_y);
 
    // should we override thumb image type?
    $this->image_type = ($this->image_type != -1 ? $this->image_type : $orig_img_type);
 
    // check for allowed image types
    if ($orig_img_type < 1 or $orig_img_type > 3) die("Image type not supported");
 
    if ($orig_x > $this->max_x or $orig_y > $this->max_y) {
 
      // resize
      $per_x = $orig_x / $this->max_x;
      $per_y = $orig_y / $this->max_y;
      if ($per_y > $per_x) {
        $this->max_x = $orig_x / $per_y;
      }
      else {
        $this->max_y = $orig_y / $per_x;
      }
 
    }
    else {
      // keep original sizes, i.e. just copy
      if ($this->save_to_file) {
        @copy($from_name, $to_name);
      }
      else {
        switch ($this->image_type) {
          case 1:
              header("Content-type: image/gif");
              readfile($from_name);
            break;
          case 2:
              header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
              readfile($from_name);
            break;
          case 3:
              header("Content-type: image/png");
              readfile($from_name);
            break;
        }
      }
      return;
    }
 
    if ($this->image_type == 1) {
      // should use this function for gifs (gifs are palette images)
      $ni = imagecreate($this->max_x, $this->max_y);
    }
    else {
      // Create a new true color image
      $ni = ImageCreateTrueColor($this->max_x,$this->max_y);
    }
 
    // Fill image with white background (255,255,255)
    $white = imagecolorallocate($ni, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefilledrectangle( $ni, 0, 0, $this->max_x, $this->max_y, $white);
    // Create a new image from source file
    $im = $this->ImageCreateFromType($orig_img_type,$from_name);
    // Copy the palette from one image to another
    imagepalettecopy($ni,$im);
    // Copy and resize part of an image with resampling
    imagecopyresampled(
      $ni, $im,             // destination, source
      0, 0, 0, 0,           // dstX, dstY, srcX, srcY
      $this->max_x, $this->max_y,       // dstW, dstH
      $orig_x, $orig_y);    // srcW, srcH
 
    // save thumb file
    $this->SaveImage($ni, $to_name);

    if($temp) {
      unlink($tmpfname); // this removes the file
    }

  }

}

?>
```

Second file named (thumb.php)

```js
<?php

###############################################################
# Thumbnail Image Generator 1.3
###############################################################
# Visit http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/ for updates
############################################################### 

// REQUIREMENTS:
// PHP 4.0.6 and GD 2.0.1 or later
// May not work with GIFs if GD2 library installed on your server 
// does not support GIF functions in full

// Parameters:
// src - path to source image
// dest - path to thumb (where to save it)
// x - max width
// y - max height
// q - quality (applicable only to JPG, 1 to 100, 100 - best)
// t - thumb type. "-1" - same as source, 1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG
// f - save to file (1) or output to browser (0).

// Sample usage: 
// 1. save thumb on server
// http://www.zubrag.com/thumb.php?src=test.jpg&dest=thumb.jpg&x=100&y=50
// 2. output thumb to browser
// http://www.zubrag.com/thumb.php?src=test.jpg&x=50&y=50&f=0


// Below are default values (if parameter is not passed)

// save to file (true) or output to browser (false)
$save_to_file = true;

// Quality for JPEG and PNG.
// 0 (worst quality, smaller file) to 100 (best quality, bigger file)
// Note: PNG quality is only supported starting PHP 5.1.2
$image_quality = 100;

// resulting image type (1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG)
// enter code of the image type if you want override it
// or set it to -1 to determine automatically
$image_type = -1;

// maximum thumb side size
$max_x = 100;
$max_y = 100;

// cut image before resizing. Set to 0 to skip this.
$cut_x = 0;
$cut_y = 0;

// Folder where source images are stored (thumbnails will be generated from these images).
// MUST end with slash.
$images_folder = '/www/images/';

// Folder to save thumbnails, full path from the root folder, MUST end with slash.
// Only needed if you save generated thumbnails on the server.
// Sample for windows:     c:/wwwroot/thumbs/
// Sample for unix/linux:  /home/site.com/htdocs/thumbs/
$thumbs_folder = '/www/thumbs/';


///////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////// DO NOT EDIT BELOW
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

$to_name = '';

if (isset($_REQUEST['f'])) {
  $save_to_file = intval($_REQUEST['f']) == 1;
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['src'])) {
  $from_name = urldecode($_REQUEST['src']);
}
else {
  die("Source file name must be specified.");
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['dest'])) {
  $to_name = urldecode($_REQUEST['dest']);
}
else if ($save_to_file) {
  die("Thumbnail file name must be specified.");
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['q'])) {
  $image_quality = intval($_REQUEST['q']);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['t'])) {
  $image_type = intval($_REQUEST['t']);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['x'])) {
  $max_x = intval($_REQUEST['x']);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['y'])) {
  $max_y = intval($_REQUEST['y']);
}

if (!file_exists($images_folder)) die('Images folder does not exist (update $images_folder in the script)');
if ($save_to_file && !file_exists($thumbs_folder)) die('Thumbnails folder does not exist (update $thumbs_folder in the script)');

// Allocate all necessary memory for the image.
// Special thanks to Alecos for providing the code.
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

// include image processing code
include('image.class.php');

$img = new Zubrag_image;

// initialize
$img->max_x        = $max_x;
$img->max_y        = $max_y;
$img->cut_x        = $cut_x;
$img->cut_y        = $cut_y;
$img->quality      = $image_quality;
$img->save_to_file = $save_to_file;
$img->image_type   = $image_type;

// generate thumbnail
$img->GenerateThumbFile($images_folder . $from_name, $thumbs_folder . $to_name);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not nearly as easy as you may think.

To answer your question:

> I want to build a website that offers online tools like "email extracting", "image resizing", etc, and I was wondering how to install tools with small PHP scripts like 1-2 .php files, and have them on different pages in the existing website

For each tool you want to integrate, you will want to create a separate plugin. This plugin can be as simple as a single PHP file but I'm guessing they are going to be more complex.

Some of the plugins you create will need admin pages unless you are planning on running them just on your own website. In these cases, it's safe to use a config file and just set the needed options there. it's not ideal, but it is quicker than creating an admin page.

Yes, some of your plugins will need database access. You wouldn't create a new database just for them though. Whenever possible, work within WordPress' existing DB structure. You have a lot of different tools at your disposal for saving off options both permanently and temporarily. As a last option, you could create your own table in the database just for your plugins but I would not do that unless there is absolutely no way to use the existing structures.

For integrating them into pages, the easy way is to use short codes. The modern way is to use Gutenberg blocks. Blocks take more time to code but if you are planning on selling/distributing these tools, people will expect them. If you are just using these on your own, a short-code would probably suffice.

Sorry I don't have a better answer for you but honestly, what you are asking is a lot of work. (and I've not even touched on auditing the code for security issues before integrating it into your site!)

Cheers! :)

=C=

Comment: Good answer but to be honest, it could be done with one plugin. And let's be honest about shortcodes. While Gutenblob may have it's uses, a shortcode is still the easiest way for the end user to link to a plugin output.  Copy, paste. Whereas it could take 5 min of digging to find that block in the editor regardless of what they expect.

Comment: Yes, it could be done with a single plugin. It's still not a good idea and it is never going to be an easy idea. For that matter, you could do the entire thing in the theme's functions.php, but I don't recommend that either. :)

If I were hired to do this, I would separate the code into different plugins so that if there are issues, a single function can be turned off without affecting the rest of the site. 

Cheers! :)
=C=

Comment: Whereas if I were hired, I'd do just one as I live by the wppb.me boilerplate which makes all of my plugins rather large. I'd take the Commodore 64 programmers stance: there's no internet so make sure it works right the first time. Oh how times have changed. ;)

Comment: Thank you @CalEvans for your feedback. I get the idea now and you confirmed my understanding that it's not an easy task nor it has a simple fix for non tech guys like me to use.

Comment: @uPrompt I tried using a plugin called "insert PHP code snippets" but it didn't work as there are 2 PHP scripts so I couldn't get it to work with this script. It worked for other scripts that had 1 file so I could paste it directly there. But to Cal's point, the plugin also didn't work for other scripts with one .php file (maybe the problem is with the script)

Comment: Doc, I run a computer repair shop, write plugins and build websites. I've got almost 40 years working on computers, 35 in writing code and 10+ with php.  There's a very good reason why I don't have a PDR on my desk. If you want to learn php, wonderful! Start with "Hello World," not brain surgery.  I can instantly spot why those scripts wouldn't work with that php plugin. I could recommend a solution but it would be like you trying to explain to me how to remove an appendix. My serious suggestion, learn the basics first or hire someone. Medicine and php are rarely plug-and-play.

Comment: For example. That script above attempts to generate a thumbnail image and save it to a file. It makes no attempt to delete those files. Even if you did get it to work, what happens when someone decides to be an ass and spam your site with the resizing of 10,000 images?  It's rarely the surgery that kills you. It's the complications that arise.

Comment: Valid point on learning the basics @uPrompt . Thank you